# Is $(a+bX,X)$ jointly normal when $X$ is normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normal random variable and $Y=a+bX$, where $a,b$ are just some constants.

Then, is it true that $(Y,X)$ are jointly normal? If yes, how can I easily see that?

Thanks!

Comment: Just follow the calculation which is made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167408/144421) by [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did)

Comment: Too complicated. But maybe I got it now, can you confirm: As Y is linear in X, all linear combinations of X and Y are linear in X and hence normal. Per definition, if all linear combinations of two normal variables (here: X,Y) are normal, they are jointly normal.

Comment: @callculus In that link, $Y\mid X$ is normal. Here, $Y$ is normal.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Then the dispersion matrix of $(Y,X)$ is

\begin{align}
\Sigma=\sigma^2\begin{pmatrix}b^2 & b \\ b & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Since $\Sigma$ does not have full rank, the joint distribution of $(Y,X)$ is a [degenerate bivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case).

The degenerate bivariate normal is not expected to possess all the regular properties of the usual (nonsingular) bivariate normal. Notably,  $(Y,X)$ does not enjoy a joint density.

You can see this from the fact that the correlation $\rho$ between $Y$ and $X$ satisfies $\rho^2=1$. In other words there exists a perfect linear relationship between $Y$ and $X$, with the random point $(Y,X)$ falling on a fixed line with probability one.

For details on this degenerate distribution, check out [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263525/119261) excellent post on *Cross Validated*.

Answer (score 0):

I have some doubt to say no or yes. but I can say:

$(a+bX,X)$ have not joint density ( singular distribution )

$(a+bX,X)$ **has not joint density$**

$(Y|X=x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
x & p=1 \\
o.w & p=0
\end{array}
\right.
$ $\hspace{1cm}$ (1)

$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=P(A)=E(I_A)=E(E(I_A)|X)
=\int E(I_A|X=t) f_X(t) dt=\int E(I_{(X\leq x, Y\leq y)}|X=t) f_X(t) dt\overset{(1)}{=}
\int E(I_{(X\leq x, a+bX\leq y)}|X=t) f_X(t) dt=
\int E(I_{(t\leq x, a+bt\leq y)}|X=t) f_X(t) dt=
\int E(I_{(t\leq x, t\leq \frac{y-a}{b})}|X=t) f_X(t) dt=
\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x,\frac{y-a}{b})} E(I_{(t\leq x, t\leq \frac{y-a}{b})}|X=t) f_X(t) dt+0=\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x,\frac{y-a}{b})} E(1|X=t) f_X(t) dt=
\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x,\frac{y-a}{b})}  f_X(t) dt=F_X(\min(x,\frac{y-a}{b}))
$

so it easy now to say $(a+bX,X)$ have not joint density.

$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=F_X(\min(x,\frac{y-a}{b}))$

$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\frac{d^2}{dx dy}F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=0$

this is a singular distribution. so ,  p.d.f of(X,Y) are not normal density.

**to say yes you should check this:**

$X_{k\times 1} \sim N(\mu_{k\times 1}, \Sigma) \iff $ there exist

$\mu \in R^k $ and $A_{K\times L} \in R^{k\times L}$ such that $X_{K\times 1}=A_{K\times L}Z_{L\times 1}+\mu_{K\times 1} $ for $Z_n\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} N(0,1)$

to say yes ,so you should find $A$ such that

$\left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\ a+bX  \end{array} \right]
=A_{2\times L} Z_{L\times 1} +\mu $

go and find $A$ and check this:

( $\left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\ a+bX  \end{array} \right]$ 
and $A_{2\times L} Z_{L\times 1}  $ have a same family and  $Z_n\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} N(0,1)$ "i.i.d" )

$(Y|X=x)$ **is not a normal**

$(Y|X=x)$ is not a normal . it is a degenerated in point ${x}$. if you say
$\left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\ a+bX  \end{array} \right]$ is joint normal so
conditional distribution should be normal. note that conditional distribution  exists and not normal!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. One of the equivalent definition of jointly normal is as follow:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. We say that
a random vector $(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{m})$ is jointly normal if
there exist independent random variables $Z_{1},Z_{2},\ldots,Z_{n}$
such that $Z_{j}\sim N(0,1)$ for each $j=1,\ldots,n$ and for each
$i=1,\ldots,m$, $X_{i}\in\mbox{span}\{1, Z_{1},Z_{2},\ldots,Z_{n}\}$
(i.e., $X_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{ij}Z_{j}+\beta_i$ for some $\alpha_{ij},\beta_i\in\mathbb{R}$).
Beware of degerated cases, for example, $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ is regarded
as jointly normal.

We go back to your case. Suppose that the given $X$ is not degenerated
(i.e., $\sigma_{X}>0$). Define $Z=\frac{X-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}$,
then $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Now $a+bX\in\mbox{span}(Z)$ and $X\in\mbox{span}(Z)$,
so $(a+bX,X)$ is jointly normal.